# title on vAxis isn't set but displayed on hAxis

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Charts to display a SCATTER chart and the vAxis title is not displayed.
When I go on my chart graphic editor, I can see that my hAxis title is set but vAxis not.

For testing you can try with this simple code that reproduced the problem :

```
function test1() {
   var app = SpreadsheetApp;
   var classeur = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = classeur.getActiveSheet();
   var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B7");
   var data = [
          ['Age', 'Weight'],
          [ 8,      12],
          [ 4,      5.5],
          [ 11,     14],
          [ 4,      5],
          [ 3,      3.5],
          [ 6.5,    7]
        ];
   range.setValues(data);

   var chart = sheet.newChart()
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.SCATTER)
     .addRange(range)
     .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
     .setOption('title','title')
     .setOption('width', 300)
     .setOption('height',  400)
    .setOption('hAxis', {title: 'labelX'})
    .setOption('vAxis', {title: 'labelY'})
     .build()
  sheet.insertChart(chart);  
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Why not grouping the options together? See the [example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart#example) provided in the official documentation for code implementation, see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I'm not using the API chart but the 
Class EmbeddedChartBuilder available in Google Apps Script. And this not allows to group option ! @Mr.Rebot